# SVG make a clip-path to scale and relocate as its container scales

Tags: javascript, svg, clip-path, svg-transforms

I have this svg:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 280 280" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
    <clipPath id="clipPath">
        <path d="M 10 10 q 49 41 100 0 c -14 46 -14 40 50 50 c -24 -1 -50 -6 -40 40 c -14 -44 -53 -73 -99 -51 Z"/>
    </clipPath>
</defs>

<rect x="5" y="5" width="190" height="90" fill="#770000" clip-path="url(#clipPath)"/>
</svg>
```

I can't use CSS styles here, just SVG. And I need to scale and relocate the clipPath as the rect scales or moves.

I tried adding this to the clipPath definition `<clipPath id="clipPath" width="190" height="90" x="5" y="5">` with no result. Tried adding these parameters to the path too. No result both times. Also tried reducing the dimensions of the `rect` the `clipPath` will truncate instead of readjusting, same thing if I change the X,Y position. Any hint on how to solve this?

Comment: convert it to objectBoundingBox units.

Comment: @RobertLongson could you provide more info on this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/clipPathUnits